# Injecting a mock of a QTimer

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, qtestlib

I'm writing a unit test with QTest for a legacy code like:

```
#include <QTimer>
class MyObject: public QObject{
    public:
        void foo(){
            t1.start(500);
        }
    private:
        QTimer t1{this};
};
```

And want to mock a QTimer and then test if the `QTimer::start(int)` is properly called. I was trying several approaches. Dependency injection with template `template<typename TIMER = QTimer> class MyObjecr: public QObject`, but getting

> Template classes not supported by Q_OBJECT

And LD_PRELOAD=libQTimerMock.so with a simple QTimer re-implementation.

```
class QTimer : public QObject
{
signals: 
    void onStarted(int);
public slots:
    void start(int i)
    {
        emit onStarted(i);
    }
};
```

Which with QMetaObject magie actually **WORKS**.

Is there a simpler way? Some compile time include injection? So the `#include <QTimer>` for MyObject.h uses the mock file and the rest of the spaghetti remains intakt?

Comment: You can also create your own abstract `class MyTimer` with the methods something like `start`, `stop`, `setCallback` and use composition with `QTimer` in production, and mock in testing. However, it will not be actually less complicated.

Comment: @pptaszni Please provide a code example. I've been googling the heck out of this problem and haven't seen an adequate answer anywhere. If you create an abstract class and have your class that uses the timer take that type, then QTimer would have to be derived from it. If you make some other class and use composition, you'd still need to provide some argument to the constructor to take the Mock and QTimer, and just moved the problem for the class you are testing to another class.